# Atari Game OpenAI Gym - VS studio crashes when closing the env (ie: env.close() )

Tags: python, openai-gym, atari-2600

I am trying to set up the Atari game environment and it's been a few hours that I am trying to understand why my render won't close after calling `env.close()`.

When I call `env.close()`, the render displays `Visual Studio Code is not responding. Force Quit or Wait`. I have seen a couple stackoverflow articles proposing the use of `pygame.quit()` but I have no success.

Here is my code, help would be appreciated:

```
import gym
from stable_baselines3 import a2c
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import VecFrameStack
from stable_baselines3.common.env_util import make_atari_env
from stable_baselines3.common.evaluation import evaluate_policy
import os
import pygame

environment_name = 'Breakout-v4'
env = gym.make(environment_name, render_mode='human')
# env.unwrapped.get_action_meanings()

env.metadata['render_fps'] = 150  # Or whichever fps value you prefer

env.reset()


episodes = 1
for episode in range (1, episodes+1):
    obs = env.reset()
    done = False
    score = 0

    while not done:
        env.render()
        
        action = env.action_space.sample()
        n_state, reward, done, truncated, info = env.step(action)
        score+=reward
    print('Episode:{} Score:{}'.format(episode, score))
pygame.quit()
env.close()
```

I have tried to close the environment with `env.close` and `pygame.quit()` and I am expecting that the render window disappear.